# How to post data to my facebook page automatically?

Tags: php, facebook

I need to post some data to my page on facebook automatically with php.

I've searched and done some says but no success. Most of them are very old articles and it changes a lot since then.

Could you give me a new article or video to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to `developers.facebook.com` and they have all the guides you need to get started.

Here's a link for using [their PHP API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0) in your application. Later you can read on doing things like [Posting Links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/4.0.0) and stuff like that.

Remember that you first need to have an APP ID.

All the best ;)

**Refs:**

1. [Facebook PHP API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted/4.0.0)
2. [Posting a link to a timeline - FB](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/postwithgraphapi/4.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

You need an Extended Page Token, and you need to post to the /page-id/feed endpoint.

About Extended Page Tokens (and Tokens in general):

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/extended-page-access-tokens-curl/

About the feed endpoint, see this page for code examples and information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page/feed